# How to let a class variable in python refer to a static method of the same class?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, static

I have a class that has a class variable and a static method and I need to let the class variable contain a callback to the static method.

The class looks like:

```
class Test(object):
    ref = ???? #this should be my reference

    @staticmethod
    def testmethod(anyparam="bla"):
        print "it works"
```

How can I do this? Is this even possible?

I am using python 2

EDIT:
The real example is this:

```
class reg(cmd): 

    bla = {
        'def': [ ... ],
        'rem': [ ...,
            PIPE.return_response(fail_callback=HERE_I_NEED_THE_REF),
            ...
        ]
    }

    @classmethod
    def testmethod(cls, aco):
        print "i want to see this on fail"
```

Comment: Hmm ok, but how can I reference it then in the "ref" variable? simply writing ref = Test.testmethod does not work

Comment: How about `Test.ref = 'XXX'`

Comment: not possible because in my real use case "ref" is an dict containing lists and i only need to set one element in one list of one dict to the testmethod...

Comment: I don't understand then. Can you please provide input and expected output?

Comment: seems to be not possible because when the dict is defined the class is not completely built. so I cannot refer to those functions because they are not available yet... is this right?

Comment: `PIPE.return_response(fail_callback=HERE_I_NEED_THE_REF)` calls `return_response` as `bla` is being created. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the problems of referencing the static method during class creation. `Test` isn't in the namespace yet, and even if you define `ref` below `testmethod`, the static method definition magic isn't complete. You can, however, patch the class after its created:

```
class reg(cmd): 

    bla = {
        'def': [ ... ],
        'rem': [ ...,
            PIPE.return_response(fail_callback=HERE_I_NEED_THE_REF),
            ...
        ]
    }

    @classmethod
    def testmethod(cls, aco):
        print "i want to see this on fail"

Test.ref["rem"][??] = PIPE.return_response(fail_callback=Test.testmethod)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ref = self.testmethod

    @staticmethod
    def testmethod(anyparam="bla"):
        print "it works"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define the class variable outside the class following the rest of its definition:

```
class reg(cmd):
    @classmethod
    def testmethod(cls, aco):
        print "i want to see this on fail"

reg.bla = {
        'def': [ '...' ],
        'rem': [ '...',
            PIPE.return_response(fail_callback=reg.testmethod),
            '...'
        ]
    }
```